# How do I add data source in persistence.xml so that IntelliJ IDEA sees it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, persistence, hsqldb, toplink

How do I add data source in persistence.xml so that IntelliJ IDEA sees it ?

I have little desktop application (which works as I want it to) that has following `persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="reportingPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.test.data.Company</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="SA"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:ReportingDB"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="toplink.target-database" value="HSQL"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I open class `Company.java` which looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
public class Company implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

IDEA underscores "COMPANY" and "NAME" saying data source is not defined. And yes, I don't have it in data source column if I open JPA module configuration.

[This article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/cfgdepds005.htm#TopLinkJDBC) says I should add `jta-data-source` tag to `persistence.xml` but it doesn't make datasource show up in JPA module configuration view.

I'm confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tool/Data Sources menu. It will let you add new datasource based on information in `properties` tag of your `persistence.xml`. After that you'll be able to select it in JPA module configuration window.

Comment: IDEA still says "Cannot resolve table COMPANY" when I view Company.java. Any ideas ?

Comment: I had to open up the Database tab in intellij for it to recognize the new table.